# Why Custom Report in GA does not update?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Why Custom Report in GA does not update? Maybe it takes some time for it to update? If so, how much time will it take?

Let me show you my GTM and GA setup.

Here I am sending an event, this event triggers a tag in GTM. Below you can see the tag content.
[image]
[image]

I setup two custom dimensions (with indexes 2 and 3) in GA and one custom metric (with index 2). Let me show them to you.
[image]
[image]

Also I setup a custom report in GA. Let me show its view next.
[image]

Now I am expecting to have the view in GA updated whenever the tag is fired in GTM, because the tag has indexes of the dimensions which participate in the custom report and it increments the metric which participates in the report in this line of the tag:
[image]

but the custom report does not update. I tried to wait for 5-10 minutes and it does not change. What am I missing here?

Also I verified that the fired tag actually reaches from GTM to GA by going to `Real-Time` -> `Events` in GA.
[image]
[image]

That seems to be all info about my problem. I am very new to GA, so I may miss some important for the diagnosing of the issue info, in such a case, please, ask me what I need to tell you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to wait for 5-10 minutes and it does not change.

You should wait for 24 (up to 48) hours to see all reports excluding Real Time.

It's processing latency in standard GA.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en

Comment: Yes, after something like 18hours I see the past results.